# trigger to first validate values in other table and then update

Tags: oracle, trigger

I have problem coding a trigger.

The table structure is this:

**table 1: inventory**

```
field 1: item_code(PK)
field 2: item_desc
field 3: unit_price
```

**table 2: stock_master**

```
field 1: item_code(fk)
field 2: quantity
```

**table 3: warehouse_master**

```
field 1: warehouse_code(PK)
field 2: location
field 3: description
field 4: address
```

**table 4: stock_warehouse_details**

```
field 1: stock_ware_id (PK)
field 2: item_code (FK)
field 3: warehouse_code (fk)
field 4: quantity
```

I need to create a trigger on stock_warehouse_details so that it will first validate item_code in stock_master table and warehouse_code in warehouse_master table and then with update trigger on stock_warehouse_details table, values should be added in stock_master if not present there and if values are present, update them with total quantity with each respective item_code.

I'm using Oracle

Comment: can you have stock that isn't in any warehouse?  Looks to me that the stock_master table is duplicated data that can be queried from stock_warehouse and therfore redundant